# Is mechanically separated beef legal in products in the U.S.?

Tags: food-safety, meat

I was shopping on line at a major supermarket and noticed  items from major brands that the ingredients list lists mechanically separated pork and chicken. I don't know about the pork or chicken but as for the beef I found the following link.

[https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/What-is-Mechanically-Separated-Meat-MSM#:~:text=At%20that%20time%20the%20use,for%20use%20as%20human%20food](https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/What-is-Mechanically-Separated-Meat-MSM#:%7E:text=At%20that%20time%20the%20use,for%20use%20as%20human%20food).

Comment: Regardless of legality I wouldn't buy a product with MSM in it simply because of quality reasons.

Comment: I don't know if there is a ban, at least in the US, which is generally pretty lenient compared to many other countries when it comes to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My knowledge MSM Beef was banned in 2004 but had been used since at least the 80s before that. I originally heard about this from my dad who was and is still a butcher manager.

I just texted him and he said that **MSM Beef is still prohibited for human consumption because of mad cow disease but mechanically separated Pork is legal** and can be used when the package says so. He was not sure about chicken but if it's not banned then they probably do put it in products. he says he likes that they "use as much of the animal as possible but yes , its kinda gross."

Comment: i think the beef vs pork thing got ya in the article as both are meat but only beef is banned

Comment: ....Thank you ! You are spot on. I read the label wrong. Chef Boyardee Spaghetti & Meatballs. It is only the chicken, the beef is not. Me bad. ...Have a great day and thank you again. By the way I edited the question to make ir more appropriate since I read the label wrong. :)